# What is device-width?

Tags: html, css

I am reading this [quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2013/11/screenwidth_is.html).  A few paragraphs down you get this:

> Web developers expect screen.width/height to give the number of
>   physical pixels on the entire screen. The other option, however, is
>   that it gives the width and height of the ideal viewport; the one you
>   get when using width=device-width.

What is he referring to with `width=device-width`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#Viewport_width_and_screen_width Google does not bite.

Comment: first hit in google, comon. http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `device-width` is a value that can be used as a target condition for media queries. The excerpt is referring to the fact that `device-width` may not return the actual physical number of pixels the device has. Many devices will return a "virtual" number of pixels because of their low or high pixel density screens.  A good example of devices that exhibit this behavior are iPhones and iPads with Retina displays.  [Ferrrmolina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3187989/ferrrmolina) posted a good [reference link which explains the phenomenon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#A_pixel_is_not_a_pixel), in the comments.

> `device-width` ... is the width of the rendering surface of the output
>   device. For continuous media, this is the width of the screen.
>   ... The ‘px’ unit is of the logical kind, as described in the [Units](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-3/#units) section.

https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-3/#device-width

What Quirks Mode is getting at is answered nicely [here, on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Absolute_length_units):

> For low-dpi devices, the unit px represents the physical reference
>   pixel and the others are defined relative to it. Thus, 1in is defined
>   as 96px which equals 72pt. The consequence of this definition is that
>   on such devices, length described in inches (in), centimeters (cm),
>   millimeters (mm) doesn't necessary match the length of the physical
>   unit with the same name.
>
> For high-dpi devices, inches (in), centimeters (cm), millimeters (mm)
>   are defined as their physical counterparts. Therefore the px unit is
>   defined relative to them (1/96 of 1 inch).